# I have a JSP page and on click of submit of that page the second jsp is not getting displayed

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a JSP page and on click of submit of that page it goes to the controller and then controller returns another jsp that should be dsplayed on click of the submit button but this jsp is not getting displayed

So on click of submit button my jsp is not getting displayed but when i go to developer tools->network->preview it shows the preview of my jsp that should be displayed but instead the first jsp is getting displayed.

Moreover, when i put breakpoints in my controller and then complete the execution of my program, the second jsp gets displayed. Can you please tell me why this is happening and how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Should define the navigation logic somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/YourController",
  type: "post",
  data: values,
  success: function(data){
      alert("success");
       $("#result").html(data);
  },
  error:function(){
      alert("failure");
      $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
  }   
});
```